# Change html table if device width is LOW px

Tags: html, css

I  have table which is in 1 row shows logos from both sides and About Us text between them. It is working perfect for wide screen devices, but looks compressed on small screen devices. How Can I do to make logos place under my text(on second row) on small screen devices and keep same for wide screen?

```css
/*For logos*/
.popit {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .popit {
    height: 57px;
    width: 180px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 940px) {
  .popit {
    height: 57px;
    width: 180px;
    
  }
}
/*For my Text between logos*/
.popito {
  color: #333333;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .popito {
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 800;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 940px) {
  .popito {
    font-size: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 3.5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="popit" width="33%"> <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1671" src="https://media-cf.assets-cdk.com/teams/repository/export/18f/774a0a28d100584040050568b5709/18f774a0a28d100584040050568b5709.png" alt="" width="180" height="50" /></th>
      <th width="33%">
        <div class="popito">ABOUT US</div>
      </th>
      <th class="popit" width="33%"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1671" src="https://media-cf.assets-cdk.com/teams/repository/export/18f/774a0a28d100584040050568b5709/18f774a0a28d100584040050568b5709.png" alt="" width="180" height="50" /></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: see w3 https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to make your html markup something like this:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="smalldevice">
      <th colspan=3>
        <div class="popito">ABOUT US</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="popit" width="33%"> <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1671" src="https://media-cf.assets-cdk.com/teams/repository/export/18f/774a0a28d100584040050568b5709/18f774a0a28d100584040050568b5709.png" alt="" width="180" height="50" /></th>
      <th width="33%">
        <div class="popito">ABOUT US</div>
      </th>
      <th class="popit" width="33%"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1671" src="https://media-cf.assets-cdk.com/teams/repository/export/18f/774a0a28d100584040050568b5709/18f774a0a28d100584040050568b5709.png" alt="" width="180" height="50" /></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then give the entire second row (smalldevice) a `display: none;` for the media-query you want it to be hidden and a `display: block;` when it should appear.

Do the same thing vice versa with the div in the upper row and it should work, although i've hadn't had the time to test it.

I hope it's understandable what i mean :)

regards

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `<head>`

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

This tells the browser your html is responsive.

Comment: I added, but it is still same. It is because I place them inside same`<tr>`. Meybe I need to reconstract html if device is mobile.